# RSpec API service passing array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

I make couple of test which checks my API Services. In one test i pass two parameters to api/v1/pages/1 and it works OK; Here's code

> > put "api/v1/pages/#{@page.id}", { "title" => "new title",
> >     "description" => "new description"}    last_response.status.should eql(200)

Now i'm having problems with passing array of objects to service. I was trying something but unsuccessfully.

```
 @index = build(:index) //factory girl
 @contact = build(:contact)
 put "api/v1/pages/1/menu" ,[ //need to pass @index and @contact, and/or @index.name, @contact.name]
```

Comment: Can you paste the relevant sections from `rake routes` please?

Comment: PUT    /api/v1/pages/:portfolio_id/menu(.:format)              api/v1/pages#edit_menu_items {:format=>"json"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@index = build(:index) //factory girl
@contact = build(:contact)
put "api/v1/pages/1/menu", :index => @index, :contact => @contact
```

Rails should marshal your objects on both sides.

Comment: Looks like it still not passing it right, it throws me 
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please paste the output from rspec